# Check azure function status launch by a trigger from web site

Tags: c#, typescript, azure-functions

We use `azure functions` for batch processes triggered via a blob trigger (eg excel file import). Now some treatments must also be able to be launched from the website.

This means that we must be able to import a file from the site and indicated to the user the status : success, failure?... Ideally we want to use the existing functions and thus add the file in the blob to trigger the same function.

What are the possible strategies to know if a treatment is finished as well as its status (success, failure ...) if it must be launched from the site through a web api in `C#`. We talked about long polling? SignalR? Simply create a function with a manual entry point instead of the trigger ? Are there examples of a scenario like this?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you want to launch some treatments from a website you can use an Http Triggered azure function.

If you treatments take a long time to execute and you want to be able to query the status of the treatments then you will want you Http Triggered function to launch a workflow throught Azure Durable Functions.

All you need is in the [microsoft documentation](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview). To summarize, you will end up with something like this

```
Website ----> HttpTrigger Function ----> Orchestrator Function ---> Treamtmen 1 (Activity Function)
                                                               ---> Treatment 2 (Activity Function)
                                                               ---> ....
```

The durable functions expose some [HTTP API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-http-api) to query the [status of your workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-instance-management#querying-instances). You can also set some custom status in your different functions that will handle the treatments to have a more precise view of where you are.